# Maximum number of concurrent connections exceeded

Tags: apache, optimization

**I am using Apache HTTP Server 1.3.29**

I am currently with an Apache server that is experiencing the error:

**Internal Server Error 500
Exception: EWebBrokerException
Message: Maximum number of concurrent connections exceeded. Please try again later**

This message appears when many users are using the system, but do not know the number of connections to cause this.

I need help optimize server to support more connections / access

Here is the link to the server httpd.conf view (only the important parts):

http://www.codesend.com/view/8fd87e7d6cc1c94eee30a8c45981e162/

Thanks!

Comment: what hardware are you using - looks like you may need to upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

It's not for lack of machine resources. The server has 16GB of RAM and a great processor, the problem occurs when the consumer is not even 30%, maybe some adjustment in Apache, this is the help you seek here.